# uniquely name images that are output to browser with php script

Tags: php, image-processing

I use wordpress cms. I allow selective people to upload image. I have a script that resizes it and outputs resized image back to the browser where they can right click and save it. Here is the relevant part of the code. If needed I will put up the whole code. The script works and puts the resized image in the browser nicely.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resized, null, 100); 
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode(ob_get_clean()) . '">'; 
imagedestroy($resized);
```

**ISSUE** : The form has just one upload field. I only allow images to be resized and saved one-by-one. Since all these resized images generated by the script has a same name `index`, an issue arises, which is when the visitor goes to save his image in windows the first time, say in a folder, it is saved as index.jpeg but when he goes to save images after that he is prompted to replace index.jpeg image. Because "these people " are not tech savvy so they usually replace the image end up wasting my time solving the case. So I would like these resized images to have unique name generated either by `uniqid()` or `time()`.

**WHAT I TRIED / AM TRYING** : I am confused to what phpfunction I should be using here together with `time()` so that I could create a new filename each time a resized images is generated. In order to first set a variable, i tried to use `basename()` function like this, but it wont work.

```
$new_filename = basename($resized); echo '<br>' .$new_filename. '<br>';
```

Obviously it throws a `warning:basename() expects parameter 1 to be string`. I tried that and realized that in this case the variable `$resized` is a resource not a string. I am still crawling through threads for [imagejpeg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) at php.net in search of a solution, have not found any resource yet.

---

> Bottomline question : how do I set or get a variable for resized file so
>   that I can manipulate it alongwith `time()` to create new names each
>   time.

---

FINAL UPDATE : @CBroe, pointed out that this is not possible so I am off to looking for an alternative.

Comment: Why are you sending a `Content-type: image/jpeg` header, when you output HTML code after that? That makes no sense; is actually wrong. And you can not specify a desired filename when outputting an image inline like this. (If you were to force an automatic download of the image, that would be a different matter.)

Comment: @CBroe I made these mistakes (apparently) mostly because I am just learning these things. Now that you pointed it out i will make the correction. Also can you point me to a resource about "forcing an automatic download of the image". Since I need the images to have unique names everytime, maybe I will find that as my solution. i will have to try that anyways, as you said this will not work. thanks.

Comment: _“Also can you point me to a resource about "forcing an automatic download of the image".”_ – gladly, that resource has a name: _Google_. As for unique file names/identifiers: Look into PHP functions uniqid, tempnam, tmpfile